# To expose MS CRM to the internet: Should we use IFD or something like Forefront UAG?

Tags: microsoft-forefront-2010, microsoft-dynamics-crm

In our company we plan to expose our MS CRM 2011 system to the internet to make it easier to access from the outside.
As far as I can see there are basically 2 alternatives:

1. Make an Internet Facing Deployment (IFD)
2. Using software like Forefront UAG

Our network guy means a simple IFD solution wouldn't be secure enough since MS CRM itself might be unsecure and we definitely need Forefront UAG or a similiar 3rd party solution (with web application firewall etc).

What do you mean? Is a IFD deployment secure? Which approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft announced FF UAG/TMG are End of Life. The current versions are the last that will be released (according to the announcement, MS is a little schizo sometimes). You should expose Dynamics CRM using the IFD (Internet Facing Deployment).

CRM is secure if deployed properly. Contact your reseller/partner if you have serious concerns. If you follow the directions from MS your biggest security vulnerability is almost universally the strength of users' passwords.